# How many distinguishable ways are there to place all twelve animals in a circle?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a problem I made up!

A zoo keeper has 12 animals: 3 indistinguishable black horses,  1 gray horse, 4 indistinguishable lions, and 4 indistinguishable giraffes. He wants to arrange them all in a circle so that the crowd is "pleased." The crowd is "pleased" only when the following are  true.

1) A lion is not directly behind a giraffe.

2) A horse is not directly behind a lion.

3) A giraffe is not directly behind a black horse.

4) A giraffe is in front of the gray horse.

If all twelve animals must be placed and animals cannot be stacked, how many distinguishable ways are there to do so?

Comment: Yes, but what is the zoo keeper's motivation? What is the backstory?

Comment: Animals stacked?

Comment: Some strange people out there might try to stack the poor animals :P

Comment: Since they are all in a circle, how does one define "directly behind" versus "in front"?

Comment: What do you mean? There can still be a distinction...

Comment: I know, I just want to make sure that I'm understanding you correctly. -- that the restriction only works in one direction

Comment: Yep, so rule 4 can be "a gray horse is directly behind a giraffe"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is 80.

Computed by brute force, assuming that the circle remains the same even if you rotate it, i.e. assuming that shifting the circle as a whole does not result in a different circle which should be counted separately.

I write `G` for giraffe, `L` for lion and `b` resp. `g` for black resp. gray horse. I require the cyclic version of this string to contain the word `Gg` but forbid the words `GL`, `Lb` and `bG`, which encodes your four rules. Then the following 80 permutations and their cyclically shifted versions are still permissible:

```
gGGGbbbLLLLG gGbbLLGbLLGG gLLGGGbbbLLG gbLGbbLLLGGG
gGGbLGbbLLLG gGbbLLLGGbLG gLLGGbLGbbLG gbLLGGGbbLLG
gGGbLLGbbLLG gGbbLLLGbLGG gLLGGbbLGbLG gbLLGGbLGbLG
gGGbLLLGbbLG gGbbbLLLLGGG gLLGGbbbLLGG gbLLGGbbLLGG
gGGbbLGbLLLG gLGGGbbbLLLG gLLGbLGGbbLG gbLLGbLGGbLG
gGGbbLLGbLLG gLGGbLGbbLLG gLLGbLGbbLGG gbLLGbLGbLGG
gGGbbLLLGbLG gLGGbLLGbbLG gLLGbbLGGbLG gbLLGbbLLGGG
gGGbbbLLLLGG gLGGbbLGbLLG gLLGbbLGbLGG gbLLLGGGbbLG
gGbLGGbbLLLG gLGGbbLLGbLG gLLGbbbLLGGG gbLLLGGbbLGG
gGbLGbLGbLLG gLGGbbbLLLGG gLLLGGGbbbLG gbLLLGbbLGGG
gGbLGbLLGbLG gLGbLGGbbLLG gLLLGGbbbLGG gbbLGGGbLLLG
gGbLGbbLLLGG gLGbLGbLGbLG gLLLGbbbLGGG gbbLGGbLLLGG
gGbLLGGbbLLG gLGbLGbbLLGG gbLGGGbbLLLG gbbLGbLLLGGG
gGbLLGbLGbLG gLGbLLGGbbLG gbLGGbLGbLLG gbbLLGGGbLLG
gGbLLGbbLLGG gLGbLLGbbLGG gbLGGbLLGbLG gbbLLGGbLLGG
gGbLLLGGbbLG gLGbbLGGbLLG gbLGGbbLLLGG gbbLLGbLLGGG
gGbLLLGbbLGG gLGbbLGbLLGG gbLGbLGGbLLG gbbLLLGGGbLG
gGbbLGGbLLLG gLGbbLLGGbLG gbLGbLGbLLGG gbbLLLGGbLGG
gGbbLGbLLLGG gLGbbLLGbLGG gbLGbLLGGbLG gbbLLLGbLGGG
gGbbLLGGbLLG gLGbbbLLLGGG gbLGbLLGbLGG gbbbLLLLGGGG
```

Here is the core of my code (in Python):

```
from itertools import permutations
perm = set('g'+''.join(x)+'G' for x in permutations("bbbLLLLGGG"))
perm = [x for x in perm if not any(y in x for y in ["GL", "Lb", "bG"])]
```

I figure that attacking these rules with inclusion/exclusion, and doing so correctly, will be more work than this brute force computation.

Comment: You mean to say that there are only 80 of them altogether?.  Still cannot follow your method. In the case of inclusion and exclusion, you are eliminating potential culprits and allowing for non culprits to exist.  Could you comment on my method to find what is wrong, I cannot digest that there is so much difference between our answers. Let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: @satish: I used code similar to http://ideone.com/AvFKVl. Originally I wrote this for Sage, but it's essentially just Python I used, so it's easy to turn into pure Python.

Answer (score 0):

Total Number of ways =$$\frac{(12-1)!}{4!4!3!}$$ = 11550

Now, what you don't want is LG(Hg)HLG(Hg)HLG(Hg)HLG.  Let HgHLG = one object.

Number of ways :HgHLG_ _ _ _ _ _ _ G = $$\frac{(7)!}{2!2!3!}= 210$$ Multiply this 7 times (moving in the musical chair) = 7*210 = 1470

Now we will have to add back: HgHLGHLG _ _ _ _ G= $$\frac{(4)!}{2!}*2 = 24$$.  (2 because Hg can find two places in this configuration. Further, Multiply this 4 times = 24*4 = 96

Now we will have to subtract: GHgHLGHLGHLGL = 3 (because Hg can find three places in this configuration).

It may not be that accurate.  But the idea behind is Principle of Inclusion Exclusion.

Thus the Number of ways =$$ 11550 - 1470+96-3 = 10173$$

Comment: Turning from a comment to my answer to your answer, since that's what I'll discuss. I must confess I find it hard to follow. You don't introduce your notation. Is HgHLG=“Horse gray, Hose black, Lion, Giraffe”? Why would that be one object? Is that supposed to catch the forbidden cases? But if so, it seems you only forbid those cases where several rules are violated at once. I also don't see your answer catering for the cyclic nature of this question. Even if overall position should matter (contrary to my accepted answer), the rules as to what is forbidden definitely apply cyclically.

Comment: You are right on my notation, Now I understand why my solution is wrong.  I am only finding culprits that violates all the rules at once.  That is the point which is very helpful to realize that my answer is wrong.

Comment: Did you run simulation on it to find the correct permutations.  I am asking this out of curiosity.  Let me know